# Angular Routing: highlight parent menu-item of active sub menu-item

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have some trouble of using ngClass. I can't hightlight proper menu item if it's submenu item is active. I guessed for menu item ngClass will look like:

```
ng-class="{activeMenu: [isActive('/view1'), isActive('/view2')]}"
```

But it doens't work. Here full example http://jsfiddle.net/vrvz9m5n/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ng-class="{activeMenu: isActive('/view1') || isActive('/view2')}"
```

insted of

```
ng-class="{activeMenu: [isActive('/view1'), isActive('/view2')]}"
```

you pass an array to class property - should be boolean